# Lie algebras isomorphism $gl(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong sl(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}$

Tags: lie-algebras, vector-space-isomorphism

Having a struggle finding a lie algebra homomorphism between these two spaces. So i know that $\mathbb{C} \cong \lambda\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\ \end{array} \right)
$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. A basis for $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ is $ \{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & -1  \\ \end{array} \right),  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right),  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\
1 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right) \}$.

The dimension of $< \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\ \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & -1  \\ \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\
1 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)>$ is 4, and so this space generates $gl(2,\mathbb{C})$. So these two spaces are isomorphic as vector spaces, but I can't seem to find a function that would induce a lie algebra isomorphic. I tried defining a homomorphism by

$\varphi : gl(2,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow sl(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}$

by,

$\varphi(A) = (\varphi_1(A),\varphi_2(A))$

where $\varphi_1(A) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & -a  \\ \end{array} \right)$

$\varphi_2(A)= tr(A)$

where $ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\ \end{array} \right)
$
but this did not preserve the lie bracket. Any insight as to what this homomorphism would be?